# Java SAXParser cannot read imported XML files in resource directory

Tags: java, xml, string, xml-parsing, saxparser

Can anybody help with

I've a XSD file inside a directory called GML-XSD and using Netbeans 8.0.2 and inside the source code I use a String to this file

```
String gmlXSDFile = "etc/GML_XSD/epsg/EPSG.xsd";
```

The directory is project/GML-XSD/epsg/EPSG.xsd
The problem is when I build the project and run it on Glassfish Server or Jetty, it complains about cannot find etc folder. How can I fix this to make sure it will try to find "etc/GML_XSD" inside the war file but not the directory where it is deployed.

Thanks.

```
 Failed to read schema document 'file:/usr/local/ras/log/etc/GML_XSD/epsg/EPSG.xsd', because 1) could not find the document
```

Edit: Code to read this file (not work)

```
Source[] sources = new StreamSource[1];
sources[0] = new StreamSource(new File(gmlXSDFile));
```

Edit: New code inside image with

```
 String gmlXSDFile = "/GML/epsg/EPSG.xsd";
```

can support to read EPSG.xsd file correctly, but  it cannot import other xsd file belonged to other packages below:

```
  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="../gml/3.2.1/gml-3.2.1.xsd"/>
```

**Cannot resolve the name 'gml:Definition' to a(n) 'element declaration' component**

[image]

Comment: provide code how you are reading or accessing the file

Comment: I've edited this read from a new file.

Comment: Error seems like a xml validation not a failure to load the resource.Do you have the full stacktrace of this eexception.

Comment: Actually it is from "imported XSD", because if I change from getResourceAsStream to new StreamSource(new File("GML/epsg/EPSG.xsd")); then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many way and could not work, eventually I've made it with just

```
  URL schemaURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("GML/epsg/EPSG.xsd");


  Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaURL);
```

and without to need to create any package or resources package that cannot help anything. I'm so happy now.